# Realm Object Servers "Token expired warnings" normal?

Tags: react-native, realm

After running the Realm Object Server for a few days with 1k users I find a lot of "Token expired" warnings in the logs like the following:

```
...
info: [http] 174.214.2.XXX - POST /auth HTTP/1.1 200 912 - 44.937 ms
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1 200 73 - 19.172 ms
error: [sync] Sync Connection[41887]: Session[2]: Token expired (signed_user_token='...+1RFAMxHDevcmAl1ywSAAWnGS39w==').
error: [sync] Sync Connection[41887]: Session[2]: Token expired (message_type='bind', signed_user_token='...+1RFAMxHDevcmAl1ywSAAWnGS39w==').
info: [http] 174.214.2.XXX - POST /auth HTTP/1.1 200 912 - 48.745 ms
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1 200 43 - 7.368 ms
...
```

Is that normal? Is it save to ignore? because I don´t see a "Connection closed" or "terminated" error after these?

Comment: You can try 4.4.0-SNAPSHOT and see if it helps anything

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what do you mean? I don't understand

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-java#using-snapshots

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ah I see! any idea how to do this with react native: https://github.com/realm/realm-js ?